# How to access Python variables notebook from python script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

How to access Python variables (for example a Pandas dataframe in a Jupyterlab notebook) from a python script ?

I need to access a Dataframe locally (while I'm working in a notebook) from a python script.

I need to access it without having to type more lines of code in the notebook, I am looking to establish a connection to the notebook from a python script.

Comment: Could you store the variable you need and perform your test on the stored variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this and I'm not sure I know which one is most suitable based on your description thus far:

If you are running a notebook and have a dataframe in-memory in the current namespace of the running notebook, let's say `my_df` for example, you can call and run a Python script in the current namespace using `%run -i my_script.py` to invoke the script with the `i` flag for interactivity so that it is running in the current notebook namespace. (See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) for more about the magic run command and the `-i` flag.) In other words, inside the script invoked in that way, `my_df`, originally assigned in the active notebook, would be accessible as `my_df`.

If you are using JupyterLab you can attach a console to a kernel and query the namespace that way. Since the console is IPython actually, you can also use the `%run -i my_script.py` to invoke the script you are developing and the current namespace will be accessible from there, too. See [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/code_console.html#code-consoles) in the documentation, although as I noted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/console-would-not-automatically-run-code-typed-in-notebook-kernel/12512/2?u=fomightez) the last time I checked some of the specifics were outdated.

Comment: Ok thanks it's interesting ! I need to launch statistical test and datavisualisation "automatically"